# Upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.1

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, update-manager, lts, do-release-upgrade

How long should I wait until the warning of new LTS release upgrade will appear on update-manager? After 5 days from the first point release (20.04.1) nothing appears...
I enabled "notify me on new LTS"...